# Xtreamer Sidewinder 3 get stuck

Tags: streaming

Every time I run 1080P/720P bluray files on the Xtreamer from my computer via wirelees or wired network connection, the movie bumps and doesn't run smooth.
I bought the streamer about 2 weeks ago, and it has firmware 3.5, the newest.
can anyone help me solve the problem?

Comment: I assume you meant to type 'stuck'? :)

Comment: oh, yeah XD
Just noticed that xd